# How to convert base64 to Integer in Crypto++?

Tags: c++, base64, crypto++, bigint

I use Crypto++ library. I have a base64 string saved as CString. I want to convert my string to Integer. actually this base64 built from an Integer and now i want to convert to Integer again.but two Integer not equal.in the other words second Integer not equal with original Integer.

```
Base64Decoder bd;
CT2CA s(c);
std::string strStd(s);

bd.Put((byte*)strStd.data(), strStd.size());
bd.MessageEnd();

word64 size = bd.MaxRetrievable();
vector<byte> cypherVector(size);

string decoded;
if (size && size <= SIZE_MAX)
{
    decoded.resize(size);
    bd.Get((byte*)decoded.data(), decoded.size());
}

Integer cipherMessage((byte*)decoded.data(), decoded.size());
```

Comment: How did you make out with this issue? If the code below does not work for you, then we will need to see some Base64 encoded data so we can run your program with real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> string decoded;
> if (size && size <= SIZE_MAX)
> {
>     decoded.resize(size);
>     bd.Get((byte*)decoded.data(), decoded.size());
> }
> ```

You have a string called `decoded`, but you never actually decode the data by running it through a [`Base64Decoder`](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64Decoder).

Use something like the following. I don't have a MFC project handy to test, so I'm going to assume you converted the `CString` to a `std::string`.

```
// Converted from Unicode CString
std::string str;

StringSource source(str, true, new Base64Decoder);
Integer value(val, source.MaxRetrievable());
std::cout << std::hex << value << std::endl;
```

The `StringSource` is a `BufferedTransformation`. The `Integer` constructor [you are using is](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_integer.html):

```
Integer (BufferedTransformation &bt, size_t byteCount, Signedness sign=UNSIGNED, ByteOrder order=BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER)
```

In between the `StringSource` and the `Integer` is the `Base64Decoder`. its a filter that decodes the string on the fly. So data flows from the source (`StringSource`) to the sink (`Integer` constructor).

Also see [Pipelines](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to achieve this. It uses some Qt classes but it should be simple to replace them:

```
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QScopedArrayPointer>

#include <crypto++/base64.h>
#include <crypto++/rsa.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;

Integer convertBase64ToCryptoPpInt(const QByteArray &base64)
{
    Base64Decoder decoder;
    decoder.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(base64.data()), base64.size());
    decoder.MessageEnd();
    const word64 size = decoder.MaxRetrievable();
    QScopedArrayPointer<byte> decoded{new byte[size]};
    decoder.Get(decoded.data(), size);
    return {decoded.data(), size};
}

QByteArray convertCryptoPpIntToBase64(const Integer &i)
{
    // Copy content of i into byte array
    const unsigned iLen = i.ByteCount();
    QScopedArrayPointer<byte> idata{new byte[iLen]};
    i.Encode(idata.data(), iLen);

    // Encode data
    Base64Encoder encoder;
    encoder.Put(idata.data(), iLen);
    encoder.MessageEnd();
    const int encodedSize = encoder.MaxRetrievable();
    QScopedArrayPointer<byte> encoded{new byte[encodedSize]};
    encoder.Get(encoded.data(), encodedSize);

    return {reinterpret_cast<char*>(encoded.data()), encodedSize};
}
```

It may be much more compact using [CryptoPP's pipelining](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) but i didn't find out how to stream from and to a `CryptoPP::Integer`.